# Is usage of "in more detail" at the beginning of a sentence awkward?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Is usage of **"in more detail"** as an equivalent of "to explain in more detail" at the beginning of a sentence awkward? (see example below)

> In this chapter we present the evaluation setup. **In more detail**, we define the dataset and the location and time models. We then introduce...

if it is not idiomatic, what is the correct equivalent that can be used?

Comment: If all you are doing is putting more detail on the *immediately preceding* sentence, then all you need is "That is,".

Answer (score 1):

I would re-word this to get a better 'flow' as in

In this chapter we present the evaluation setup and define the data set, the location and time models. We then introduce...

Comment: And if you wanted to capture the "essence" of what the chapter's for, as "_In this chapter we present the evaluation setup._" does, make the _title_ of the chapter "_Evaluation Setup_"

Comment: Does one need to set a comma after "In this chapter, (...)"?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this equivalent (using **more specifically**):

> In this chapter we present the evaluation setup. **More specifically**, we define the dataset and the location and time models and introduce...